# Допустим ли вызов деструктора в данной ситуации?

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, деструктор

Пишу класс двусвязного списка, и у меня появилась необходимость перегрузить operator=. Кусок класса

```
    template<class T>
class List : public Collection<T> {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        Node *_next;
        Node *_prev;
        T _data;
    };

    Node *_head;
    Node *_tail;

public:
    List() : _head(nullptr), _tail(nullptr) {}

    List(const T arr[]){
        for(const T &n: arr)
            this->push_back(n);
    }

    List(const List & copy): _head(nullptr), _tail(nullptr) {
        Node *temp = copy._head;

        while (temp != nullptr) {
            push_back(temp->_data);
            temp = temp->_next;
        }
    }

    ~List() {
        while (_head) {
            _tail = _head->_next;
            delete _head;
            _head = _tail;
        }
    }

    List<T> & operator=(const List & l){
        this->~List();
        Node *temp = l._head;

        while (temp != nullptr) {
            push_back(temp->_data);
            temp = temp->_next;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(const T &data) {
        Node *newNode = new Node;
        newNode->_data = data;
        newNode->_next = nullptr;

        if (is_empty()) {
            newNode->_prev = nullptr;
            _head = _tail = newNode;
        } else {
            newNode->_prev = _tail;
            _tail->_next = newNode;
            _tail = newNode;
        }
    }
};
```

Как видите, тело метода скопировано из копирующего конструктора. Я не нашёл более простого способа замены списка (я же не могу вызвать копирующий конструктор над объектом this, а потом вернуть на него ук-ль?). Если подскажете как укоротить данный оператор (по возможности), я буду также благодарен?

Comment: Что такое `push_back`, где объявление самого класса? Зачем вообще копировать тело метода из копирующего конструктора? Сделайте два метода - `clear` и `append`

Comment: Деструктор удаляет все обьекты, потом вы  создаете список, который после присваивания не существует более(бессмысленно) и возвращаете обьект, где все указатели указывают на несуществующие обьекты(тройная ошибка в одном операторе).  Не говоря о том, что в программе будет вызываться деструктор такого обьекта... Конечно нельзя!

Comment: @VTT Да ладно? Что такое push_back? Это вопрос к моей задаче или к методу как таковому? А зачем - я сказал. Ну раз так интересно, я кинул весь нужный кусок класса

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не удаляет, а освобождает память из-под объектов. И как ни странно, код работает

Comment: Работать будет, но поведение будет неопределенным, и  присваение выдаст неправильный результат. Понятие работает не однозначно.  Работать ожидаемым образом не будет. И еще:  освобождать память из под обьектов(как вы говорите), это  означает, что эти обьекты не будут существовать, о чем я и написал...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте функцию `swap`, которая меняет местами два списка, вернее, их внутренности. Там всего-то

```
void List::swap(List& L)
{
    Node * tmp = _head; _head = L._head; L._head = tmp;
    // То же для _tail
}
```

Тогда ваш оператор присваивания легко выражается через копирующий конструктор:

```
List<T> & List::operator=(const List & l)
{
    List<T> tmp(l);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Деструктор сам вызовется :)

Comment: Классное решение! А будет ли проще оставить параметром `List l` вместо того, чтобы в теле метода создавать новый список?

Comment: Конечно, можно и так, просто обычно все пишут оператор присваивания от константной ссылки, ну, я и не стал ломать традицию :) Ваш вариант - перенесение операции копирования в другое место, вполне годится.